# How do you create rules in BJAM?

Tags: bjam

I would like to compile a file with a specific compiler not supported on boost. I made a rule:

```
rule my_rule ( source : target )
{
    compile_specially source target ;
}

actions compile_specially
{
    my_compile_command $(my_parameters) $(1) -o $(2)
}
```

now this code builds the file into the Jamroot directory (obviously). I, however want it to be build in the regular target path (bin/gcc-4.4/release/threading-multi/...). So how do I get/generate the standard path in my_rule?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "make" target (see [BBv2 Custom Commands](http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/build/doc/html/bbv2/builtins/raw.html)). Of course this doesn't really get you what I think you are after. What you want is to create a new toolset which is considerably more complicated. You'll want to read through the [extender chapter](http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/build/doc/html/bbv2/extender.html) of the documentation. In particular the [tools and generators](http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/build/doc/html/bbv2/extending/tools.html) section. And join us in the Boost Build mail list for detailed questions and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are asking, but looks similar enough to help. In the example below I compile D language source files using gdc and eventually link them with C libraries (writing my own C functions would need to define interface d modules as d name mangling differs from C ones and would raise linking issues). I followed what is described in [tools and generators](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/extending/tools.html) section (see answer by @GrafikRobot) to achieve this and it was quite easy.

Here is sample jam files and code.

**gdc.jam**

```
import type ;
type.register D : d ;

import generators ;
generators.register-standard gdc.compile : D : OBJ ;

actions compile
{
#    "echo" $(>) $(<)
    "gdc" -c -o $(<) $(>)
}
```

**Jamroot**

```
import gdc ;

project hello
    : requirements
    <cflags>-O3
    : default-build release

;

lib gphobos2 : : <file>/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgphobos2.a <name>gphobos2 ;
lib m : : <name>m ;
lib z : : <name>z ;
lib rt : : <name>rt ;
lib pthread : : <name>pthread <link>shared ;

exe hello
    :
        hello.d
        bye.d

        gphobos2 m z rt pthread
    :
        <link>static
    ;
```

**Hello.d**

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
  writeln("Hello World!");

    static import bye ;

    bye.bye();
}
```

**Bye.d**
    module bye;

```
import std.stdio;

void bye()
{
  writeln("Good bye");
}
```